# Datatable - show/hide column group dynamically based on the selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I am using Jquery datatable in my application. My table contains the below mentioned columns:

Name, Office, A1, B1, Diff1, A2, B2, Diff2, A3, B3, Diff3, A4, B4, Diff4

Also I have a select box with the following options:
1. All 2. Diff1 3. Diff2 4. Diff3 5. Diff4

I am in need to display the datatable column groups dynamically based on the dropdown selection. That is 
1. **All** (All columns)
2. **Diff1** (Name, Office, A1, B1, Diff1)
3. **Diff2** (Name, Office, A2, B2, Diff2)
4. **Diff3** (Name, Office, A3, B3, Diff3)
5. **Diff4** (Name, Office, A4, B4, Diff4)

I have added my example in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpvcLa4h/13/) link. Here my requirement is working only for the first time. If I change the dropdown again, expected column groups was not displaying. How to fix this?

**HTML Code**:

```
<div>
    <label>Column Filter:</label>
        <select id="myCol">
      <option value="0">All</option>
      <option value="1">Diff1</option>
      <option value="2">Diff2</option>
      <option value="3">Diff3</option>
    </select>       
</div>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>A1</th>
                <th>B1</th>
                <th>Diff1</th>
                <th>A2</th>
                <th>B2</th>
                <th>Diff2</th>
                <th>A3</th>
                <th>B3</th>
                <th>Diff3</th>
                <th>A4</th>
                <th>B4</th>
                <th>Diff4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>89</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>91</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>89</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>91</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>89</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>91</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>89</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>91</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>11</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>89</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>91</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>89</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>91</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>11</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JS Code**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "paging": false
    } );

    $(document).on("change","#myCol",function(event){
    var selCol = $(this).val();
   if(selCol == 1){
       table.columns( [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ).visible( true);
       table.columns( [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] ).visible( false);
    } else if(selCol == 2){
       table.column([0, 1, 5, 6, 7]).visible(true);
       table.columns( [2,3,4,8,9,10,11,12,13] ).visible( false);
    } else if(selCol == 3){
       table.column([0,1,8, 9, 10]).visible(true);
       table.columns( [2,3,4,5,6,7,11,12,13] ).visible( false);
    } else if(selCol == 4){
       table.column([0,1,11,12,13]).visible(true);
       table.columns( [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] ).visible( false);
    } else {
       table.column([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]).visible(true);
    }

    table.columns.adjust().draw( false );
    });
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
table.columns( [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] ).visible( true);
```

after

```
var selCol = $(this).val();
```

and remove all the visible(true) from the if statements

Fiddle here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpvcLa4h/17/)

**[edit]**

```
 table.columns( ).visible( true)
```

Without defining the columns to hide worked fine too

Comment: And I think you can also remove the **else**

Answer (score 1):

A slight change in your code it will work fine:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "paging": false
    } );

    $(document).on("change","#myCol",function(event){
    var selCol = $(this).val();
   if(selCol == 1){
       table.api().columns( [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ).visible( true);
       table.api().columns( [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] ).visible( false);
    } else if(selCol == 2){
       table.api().columns([0, 1, 5, 6, 7]).visible(true);
       table.api().columns( [2,3,4,8,9,10,11,12,13] ).visible( false);
    } else if(selCol == 3){
       table.api().columns([0,1,8, 9, 10]).visible(true);
       table.api().columns( [2,3,4,5,6,7,11,12,13] ).visible( false);
    } else if(selCol == 4){
       table.api().columns([0,1,11,12,13]).visible(true);
       table.api().columns( [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] ).visible( false);
    } else {
table.api().columns([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]).visible(true);
    }

    table.api().columns.adjust().draw( false );
    });
} );
```

Hope this helps.